# Is a watcher only created for the list items that are in the DOM - Angular

Tags: angularjs

Here is an app - a watcher counter. https://jsfiddle.net/0968p1ka/ in this app I am slicing top 2 of the list items and when I add more items to the underlaying data the watcher count stays the same.
Here is a part of the app:

```
   angular.element( ".ng-scope" ).each(
                    function ngScopeIterator() {
                        // Get the scope associated with this element node.
                        var scope = $( this ).scope();
                        // The $$watchers value starts out as NULL.
                        total += scope.$$watchers
                            ? scope.$$watchers.length
                            : 0
                        ;
                    }
                );
```

Is this somewhat correct implementation of watcher counter?

My question is - are there only watchers for the Real list items located in the DOM or for every single item in the underlying array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$watchers` are created not for the list items in the DOM but for expressions you use inside them like `{{friend.name}}`. So no new expressions - no new watchers. Also I think you could use `$rootScope.$$watchersCount` to see how many of them are in your app without having to count watchers manually.

Comment: So if I show two items rendered with ng-repeat even though the model has more items - there will only be watchers created for the expressions in the two items that are in the DOM?